# Rails 5 ransack gem, syntax error, unexpected end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ransack

maybe after all day non-stop coding I'm blind, but I cant seem to find any errors, missing end's or mistypes.

I'm trying to use ransack search gem in rails 5. My code looks like this:

**ApplicationController:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :site_search

  def site_search
    @search = Post.ransack(params[:q])
    @search_posts = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end
end
```

**PostsController:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = Post.ransack(params[:q])
        @posts = @search.result(distinct: true)
    end﻿
end
```

**Form looks like this:**

```
<div id="search">
   <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
       <%= f.search_field :title_or_body_cont, placeholder: 'Type to search' %>
       <%= f.submit  %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

**Error looks like this:**

```
/.../myapp/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Extracted source (around line #6):              
4       @posts = @search.result(distinct: true)
5   end﻿
6 end * Red line here, problem with this line i guess *

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"title_or_body_cont"=>"e"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
```

Crash occurs when I click search button. There is something wrong with *site_search* method, because when its in controller, then all other Post classes methods crash too ( with same error ), but if I remove *site_search* method, then all the other methods runs fine.

Comment: when I pasted your code from `posts_controller` into editor I had as well have red point. I did not find an issue, so I just reqritten it and red point's gone: `class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Post.ransack(params[:q])
    @posts = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end
end` May be you have had some special characters from other than English keyboard?

Comment: try `ruby -w <filename>` and if it sees an unattched `end` it will tell you where the block begins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because at the end of line 5 of your posts controller, you had, before the line break, [Unicode character 65279, ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). This character was directly adjacent to the `d` in `end`. I can't speak to the exact decisions the interpreter makes about handling unusual whitespace characters in different versions of Ruby, but at a guess I suspect it was interpreting your `end*` (with `*` representing the invisible character) as a four-letter identifier that would be interpreted down the road as a variable name or method call, rather than the three-letter keyword `end`.

Comment: thanks for detailed info, new time ill know what to expect

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrey and Max, after I rewrote everything in the class it started working. **ruby -w** showed this:

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 2
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Its only warning so i guess crashes should not had happen.. Well I guess this is programming.. Moving on.

Comment: yea, and btw you have awful indentation in `posts_controller.rb` ;) convention is two spaces (no tabs)

Comment: oh, ill try to use spaces then instead, ty